# How do you create namespaced or sub-modules in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, project-structure, powershell-module

I'm familiar with writing custom PowerShell modules using the following folder structure:

```
Modules
|  +-- WebUtils
|  |  +-- WebUtils.psm1
|  +-- BuildUtils
|  |  +-- BuildUtils.psm1
```

Where you might import the webutils module by doing something like `using module WebUtils`.

I have a large ongoing project that reuses a lot of the same functionality. Right now I have a hundred or so loosely related functions in a module. The problem is that I usually only need to use 10 - 20 of them depending on the project. I would like to split up the modules in a way similar to this:

```
Modules
|  +-- Utils
|  |  +-- Web
|  |  |  +-- Web.psm1
|  |  +-- Build
|  |  |  +-- Build.psm1
|  |  +-- Utils.psm1
```

Where I could call them like `using module Utils.Web` or something similar.

How do I go about doing this? I haven't been able to find any good examples yet. Is this a good way of organizing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large modules geenrally split out into seperate modules which perform a set of related functions. A good example of this Azure or - as below - VMware PowerCLI

[image: ModuledirList]

If you `Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI` it will import all the modules. But you can import an individual module and it will only import those functions/commands and any module dependencies via them being named in the *.psd1* e.g if you only want **VMware.VimAutomation.Core** it pulls in **VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core** too

So no, not subfolders of the one module but additional related modules which can be loaded.

Comment: So the names which are made to look like namespaces are really meaningless here in function right? As in VMware.Vim could simply be named 'VimSomething' and it would work in the same way? And importing VMware wouldn't import the VMware.* modules, you would need to create a separate module that imported the **child** modules in a .psd1 or something?

Comment: Yes - the module parent is VMware.PowerCLI - which is in fact what you install - `Install-Module VMware.PowerCLI` will install ALL of these modules. Most people also use `Import-Module VMware.PowerCLI`, however this - as with your use case - also imports lots of functions/commands that are very rarely used, thus each submodule can if needed be imported individually saving import time and memory